# can I say "is this align with your design"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am communicating with a web page designer. A feature does not behaves as same as the design description. So I wanna ask him if he did this on purpose or this is a mistake. So can I ask him "is this feature align with your design?"

Comment: Yes, provided that you replace "is" with "does".

Comment: "Behavior" is more neutral than "feature."  "Feature" implies that the departure from the design is an entirely good thing.  *Is this behavior aligned with the design?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would phrase it differently. Something like: Is this *feature* intentional or a mistake?"

Align would make more sense if you were asking for an opinion if the designer thinks this or that feature fits in (i.e. aligns) or matches the rest of the design in the area.

Answer (score 1):

"is this feature align with your design?" is grammatically incorrect. Change "is" to "does" and your question is grammatically correct. Other than that, any reasonable person would be able to determine the intent of your question.